# Location icon not going away once i call client.disconnect

Tags: android, location, google-play-services

Im trying to retrieve the user's location once, then disconnect() from location services to avoid battery use. The problem is, even after i disconnect i see the location arrow icon in the status area - also the callback onDisconnected() never gets called, even after calling disconnect on the client.

This is what im doing:

In `onResume()` i connect:

```
mLocationClient = new LocationClient(this, this, this);
mLocationRequest = LocationRequest.create();
mLocationRequest.setPriority(LocationRequest.PRIORITY_HIGH_ACCURACY);
mLocationRequest.setInterval(LOCATION_UPDATE_INTERVAL);
mLocationRequest.setFastestInterval(1);
mLocationClient.connect();
```

In `onConnected()` i try getting lastlocation, if its NOT null, ill get it and disconnect from location services. If it is null, i start listening for updates:

```
if (mLocationClient.getLastLocation() != null) {
        userLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
        stopLocationServices();
        // do something which requires location
} else {
        mLocationClient.requestLocationUpdates(mLocationRequest, this);
}
```

In `onLocationChanged`

```
userLocation = mLocationClient.getLastLocation();
stopLocationServices();
// do something which requires location
```

My `stopLocationServices()` function looks like this:

```
private void stopLocationServices() {
    if (mLocationClient != null) {
        try {
            mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);
            mLocationClient.disconnect();
        } catch (Exception e) {}
    }
    mLocationClient = null;
}
```

thanks for any help.

Comment: if you want to stop location services any which way when that function is called, just make it null in the first line of the function

Comment: Tried putting null as the first line - didnt work, still see the location icon in the status area.

Comment: I have the same problem. @parampalp how have you solved? Thank you

Comment: I haven't been able to fix it, none of the solutions worked for me.

Comment: @parampalp I found an answer that worked for me: it was the my-location layer enabled on the map. http://stackoverflow.com/a/10551679/1696856

Answer (score 0):

If getLastLocation() doesn't return null and stopLocationServices() is called sequentially, you would then be trying to removeLocationUpdates() on mLocationClient without requesting them in the first place which may be throwing an exception and maybe the reason onDisconnected() is never called.

Comment: I separated the two lines `mLocationClient.removeLocationUpdates(this);` and `mLocationClient.disconnect();` into different try catch statements; it still didnt work.

Answer (score 0):

If you are still having issues with this..

I think you are setting the location client to null before it had a chance to disconnect.

Try putting this mLocationClient = null; into the onDisconnected method (remove from stopLocationServices()).

```
public void onDisconnected() {

mLocationClient = null;

}
```